# Css image is not loading

Tags: css

[image]

I Gave the path as

```
{
    position:absolute;
    Background-image:url("..img/checked.gif") ;
    padding-left: 20px; 
    margin-left: .3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #FFEBE8;  
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 170px;
}
```

Am i wrong?? Why my image is not loading?? It is saying Failed to load in firebug!! Please help me , With this..

Any links which explains giving path always welcome.

Comment: Track the request in Firebug's network tab. Look at the exact URL it's trying to load and see if it's correct. Likely it's not.

Comment: sorry to ask you i dont know much about firebug..how could i track the request?

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: in Net panel ,in Images section , my image details are showing in Red color, and the url is http://localhost:1695/User_Registration1/Stylesheets/..images/checked.gif

Answer (score 1):

Your path should be `"../images/checked.gif"`.

Fore more info, you can consult: http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: i changed it!! still nothing changed!! please see updated question for screenshot which i found in firebug,,showing error in lable.error

Answer (score 0):

in css is `Background-image:url("..img/checked.gif");` but according to screen the path is `../images/checked.gif`.

Answer (score 0):

You have no folder called `img`.